# javascript if or statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if (insurance != ("amica" || "travelers" || "national general" || "infinity" || "cincinatti")) {
    amount = "$200";
} else {
    amount = "$300";
}
```

I'm trying to have my web page display you get $200 if it's not one of the five company above.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work. I've written it several different ways
I started
`if (insurance === "amica || insurance === "travelers || ...` but nothing seems to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
if (insurance != ("amica" || "travelers" || "national general" || "infinity" || "cincinatti"))
```

It's evaluating first `("amica" || "travelers" || "national general" || "infinity" || "cincinatti")` and then checking if it's different than the insurance value.

I suppose you wanted to do:

```
if (insurance != "amica" && insurance != "travelers" && insurance != "national general" && insurance != "infinity" && insurance != "cincinatti")
```

And this could also be solved by defining an array and checking whether it includes that value:

```
const insurances = ["amica", "travelers", "national general", 
"infinity", "cincinatti"];

if (!insurances.includes(insurance))
```

Comment: okay cool thank you let me go try that. Thanks for the quick response..

Comment: then to finish your code
    {
      amount = "200";
    } else {
     amount = "300";
   }
     document.getElementById('lilDiv').innerHTML = statement + amount;


Cause it's still not working it always does the first then, never the else

Comment: Sorry, it must be ands instead of ors. I've updated the answer. I understant you want the 300 if it's one of the companies `(insurance == "amica" || insurance == "travelers"...`. The negation of that, when it's none of the 5 companies, is `(insurance != "amica" && insurance != "travelers"...` check `Morgan's law`